What are the efficient algorithms to compute Hamiltonian paths on Cayley graphs of finite groups ? Can GAP do it?
The famous Lovasz conjecture predicts existence of the Hamiltonian path on Cayley graphs. In general finding such a path is NP-complete problem, but there are many heuristic algorithms.
Question 1: For Cayley graphs of finite groups - what are the top performing algorithms ? What is known about their complexity ?
Question 2: Are there any standard packages which can do it ? Can GAP do it ? If yes how competitive is it ?

I do not have a definitive answer, but some thoughts that are too long to go in a comment - I left the question open for a few days in case someone else knew more.
It seems to be the case that all vertex-transitive graphs (except for the handful of known non-hamiltonian exceptions) have huge numbers of Hamilton cycles and heuristic algorithms will stumble on one of them pretty quickly more often than not. Vertex-transitive cubic graphs with hundreds, maybe even low thousands, of vertices can be tested reasonably quickly.
However I don't know of any programs that actually try to use the vertex-transitivity in any non-trivial way. Of course there are certain group shapes for which there is a theoretical proof that a Hamilton cycle exists, and perhaps some of the authors of these papers have implemented algorithms for actually finding one.
But if you are just given a graph along with a vertex-transitive (or even regular) group acting on it, then I don't think anyone knows how to use this information to help find a Hamilton cycle (or path).
There are of course Hamilton cycle routines for general graphs, for example in the Digraphs package in GAP, or directly in SageMath.
